# Exercise $16.3$ from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis (Second Edition). Mean value like property for analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have tried but did not solve the following problem (Exercise $16.3$) from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis Book:

> **Let $f=u+i v$ be analytic on a disk $B(a;r)$. If $0<r<R$, prove that 
>   $$f^\prime (a)=\frac{1}{\pi r}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}{u(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}} d\theta.$$**

Here is my attempt: By the Cauchy integral formula $$f^\prime(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{C_r}{\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}}dz,$$ where $C_r$ is the circle $|z-a|=r$. Also since $\overline{f(z)}$ is analytic (with the help of Cauchy-Riemann equations) on $B(a;r)$ with $\overline{f(z)}^\prime=\overline{f^\prime(z)}$, again by the Cauchy integral formula we have $$\overline{f^\prime(a)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{C_r}{\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{(z-a)^2}}dz.$$
Switching to polar coordinates and adding these two, we have
$$\frac{1}{\pi r}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}{u(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}} d\theta=f^\prime(a)+\overline{f^\prime(a)}.$$
In the Right Hand Side I obtain an extra factor $\overline{f^\prime(a)}$, actually the RHS equals to $2u_x(a)$. Did I misunderstood something ? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Be careful. When you write $\overline{f(z)}$, you need $\overline{f(\bar z)}$ if you want an analytic function.  So whereas $f'(a)+\overline{f'(a)}$ is twice the real part of $f'(a)$, this is not what your approach is calculating :)

Comment: Thanks @Ted Shifrin, I understood what I did wrong! Since $\int f(z) dz=0$, by transforming this to polar coordinates it is easy to observe that $$\int\limits_0^{2 \pi}(u(.)\cos\theta-v(.)\sin\theta)d\theta=0=\int\limits_0^{2 \pi}(u(.)\sin\theta+v(.)\cos\theta)d\theta.$$ Using this and equating the real and imaginary parts of $f^\prime(a)$, it follows that $$u_x(a)=\frac{1}{\pi r}\int\limits_0^{2 \pi}{u(.)\cos\theta}$$ and hence $$\frac{1}{\pi r}\int {u(.)e^{-i\theta}d\theta}$$ $$=u_x(a)+iv_x(a)-\frac{i}{\pi r}\int(u(.)\sin\theta+v(.)\cos\theta)d\theta=f^\prime(a)-0=f^\prime(a).$$

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar answer to yours. By the Cauchy's integral formula,
$$\begin{align*}
f'(a)= {} & \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(a,r)}\frac{f(\omega)}{(\omega-a)^2}\,d\omega=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta \\
= {} & \frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi}u(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta+\frac{i}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi}v(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta.
\end{align*}$$
Then we need to show that 
$$ \frac{i}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi}v(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi}u(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta,$$
that is,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{f(a+re^{i\theta})}e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta=0,$$
which is equivalent to
$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{i\theta})e^{i\theta}\,d\theta=0.$$
And this is clear because 
$$0=\int_{C^+(a,r)}f(z)\,dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{i\theta})ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta.$$